# jquery ajax submit form+extra data, retrieve results in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a pretty complex html form that consist of 10+ normal input fields and also a dynamic row entry that creates an array of things. Imagine having a form with Personal details and the user can also add extra rows with family member details.
I need to be able to send both 'blocks' of data to a php. A simple `$('#myForm').serialize();` wont do, because the 2nd block has to be sent as an array of things.
The problem that i am facing is this...

When i send the form values this way:

```
var frm_data = $('#myForm').serialize();
$.ajax({
    "url": "request.php?action=save",
    "data": frm_data,
    "type": "POST",
    "success": function(data) {
            var response = JSON.parse(data);
        if(response.data == "error"){
            //
        }else{
            //
        }
    }
});
```

I get each input field from the form as an associate php array. Because the 2nd block with the dynamic rows has no unique name= values...(the only distinction is their `<tr id=>`), i get only the last row's data.

```
Array
(
    [name] => George Blah
    [address] => Str. 25
    [zip] => 35510
    ...
    [extra_name] => Maria
    [extra_Tele] => 21214454
    [extra_Mobil] => 111111
    [extra_Email] => 
)
```

But i managed to create a js array of all the 'extra' rows, before i send the form, and i have it stored in a variable, which i have available.
The problem is, when i am sending **BOTH** (the form data and the 2nd block array) to the php file, the form's data is not an associated array anymore.

```
var extra = [];
//After a pretty complex function, 
//i have all the extra dynamic rows stored in this array

var frm_data = $('#myForm').serialize();
$.ajax({
    "url": "request.php?action=save",
    "data": {"form": frm_data, "extras": JSON.stringify(extra)} ,
    "type": "POST",
    "success": function(data) {
            var response = JSON.parse(data);
        if(response.data == "error"){
                //
        }else{
            //
        }
    }
});
```

And the result is like this:

```
Array
(
    [form] => name=George+Blah&address=Str+25&zip=35510&=email=&extra_name=Maria&extra_Tele=21214454&extra_Mobil=111111&extra_Email=
    [extras] => [{"extra_name":"Maria","extra_Tele":"21214454","extra_Mobil":"111111","extra_Email":""}]
)
```

I need the 'form' value to look like the 'extras' value, before it reaches the php file. I dont want to break the string sent to the php based on the '&' sign in case the user adds something like: 'George & Marry' for name, and all hell breaks lose after that.

So basically i want this:

```
[form] => name=George+Blah&address=Str+25&zip=35510&=email=&extra_name=Maria&extra_Tele=21214454&extra_Mobil=111111&extra_Email=
```

to be like this:

```
[form] => [{"name":"George Blah","address":"Str 25","zip":"35510","email":"".....}]
```

I hope i am understood. :/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, i am an idiot.

In the php file, all i had to do is:

```
parse_str($post["form"], $data);
```

Now $data holds all the $_POST results in the format i want.